# STM32F103 with LIN transceiver (MCP2004) does not work

Tags: embedded, stm32, uart, can-bus, stm32f1

I want to create a LIN bus gateway module to receive and transmit some data
But I have a problem when Sending the data from stm32f103c8t6 mcu to MCP2004E transceiver with Built in USART ,I was transmit the header just 3 byte (0x00,0x55,0x47) The data that I was transmit were 0 and FF (The data were read by Arduino that connect with LIN transceiver and voltage out from transceiver  around 12V using oscilloscope to detected)

How to know the problem and resolve it , Everyone here if you know this part don’t e shy , I want your hands please give me some advice.

Comment: I'd use the scope to check the communication lines between the MCU and the Transceiver. If the data wich are sent from the MCU to the Transceiver seen plausible, you have most probably a cabling or power supply issue. If the Chip as a Wake / CS pin, check if you drive it correctly! Watch out for negative logic!